finding index of array if the element matches an element in another array
I am trying to figure out how to find to return the indexes of an array if an element matches another element in an array.
Var list1 = [a, c, d, f, w]
Var list2 = [a, b, c, d, e]
Var list3 = [v, w, x, y, z]
If an element in list1 matches an element in list2 (so a, c and d) I want it to return the index of these elements in list2 so should return var index = [0, 2, 3]
For the index list, I want it to return the list3 elements using these indexes. So would return [v, x, y]
I have tried to use if let index = list1.indices(of: list2) but this returns an error, and I'm not sure if you can use the enumerated function?

In Swift there is not such thing as Var.
Also do you mean var list1 = ["a", "c", "d", "f", "w"]? if not
what is a, b etc...?

try this approach to achieve your goal “If an element in list1 matches an element in list2 (so a, c and d) I want it to return the index of these elements in list2 so should return var index = [0, 2, 3] For the index list, I want it to return the list3 elements using these indexes. So would return [v, x, y]”
var list1 = ["a", "c", "d", "f", "w"]
var list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
var list3 = ["v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

// common elements
let common = list1.filter { list2.contains($0) }
print("--> common: \(common)") // --> common: ["a", "c", "d"]

// indices of common elements in list2
let result: [Int] = common.compactMap{list2.firstIndex(of: $0)}
print("--> result: \(result)") // --> result: [0, 2, 3]

if let maxNdx = result.max(), maxNdx < list3.count {
    // elements in list3 from indices
    let result2 = result.compactMap{list3[$0]}
    result2.forEach{ print("--> result2: \($0.value)") }
}


did my answer not worked? If it did help you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.
